# Trouble installing GWT Developer Plugin for IE through firewall

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, plugins

I have a firewall at work, and when I try to run GwtDevPluginSetup.exe (plugin for IE browser) it tries to connect to Google and fails.  Is there another way I can install this, or hack it so that I can place required components in required directories so IE will pick them up and make it work?

And if so, is there someplace I can get these components?

Thanks!

Edit:  For those in a similar situation, I was able to download it here, even through our firewall: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10267/trunk/plugins/ie/prebuilt/gwt-dev-plugin-x86.msi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to find the actual msi. 
[Google Group discussion on this issue.](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/d4f62278589673c0)

Comment: Haha...the firewall also blocks discussion boards!  Will check it out at home, thanks.

Comment: So got it finally, though it took a little digging.  For any who are facing a similar issue, this worked for me: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r10267/trunk/plugins/ie/prebuilt/gwt-dev-plugin-x86.msi

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the last version [from GitHub](https://github.com/recastrodiaz/google-web-toolkit/blob/master/plugins/ie/prebuilt/gwt-dev-plugin-x86.msi).