# Can't download a GWT Plug In For IE

Tags: gwt, plugins, installation

I am not able to install the GWT Developer plugin for Internet Explorer.

After getting the yellow patch saying:

```
Development Mode requires the Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin
```

I click on `Download plugin`. Instead of redirecting to a download site it shows:

```
Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
```

What might be the probable cause?

Actually the page is not redirecting to :

"https://dl-ssl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B9a5e649a-ec63-4c7d-99bf-75adb345e7e5%7D%26lang%3Den%26appname%3DGWT%2520Developer%2520Plugin%2520for%2520IE%2520%2528x86%2529%26needsadmin%3Dfalse/gwt/plugins/ie/GwtDevPluginSetup.exe"

Is there any alternate way to install that plugin?

Please help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find GWT devmode plugin for IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10799647/cant-find-gwt-devmode-plugin-for-ie9)

Comment: Thanks Thomas Broyer!!!
But even installing that plugin from different site, I am not able to get perfect reult..
Its getting hanged 99% of times.. :(

Comment: Try to install the plugin directly, might help you. http://www.gwtproject.org/missing-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem and i think that there is no development mode for IE8. it didn't work when i tried to run it in IE. So i advice you to use Chrome it is the best browser supports GWT dev mode. Why do you need IE anyway ? 
read this article about IE http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/12/support-for-gwt-dev-mode-in-ie-9.html

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same issue in installing the plugin for IE, what i did was just copy and pasted the [missing plugin url](http://www.gwtproject.org/missing-plugin/) in address bar and hit the enter button. And installed it, so finally it worked. The issue was, the browser was unable to redirect to the plugins update site, after clicking on download link.

Hope this might fix your problem.