# Looking for GWT Developer Plugin for IE9 standalone installation files

Tags: gwt, plugins, internet-explorer-9

I am looking to download the standalone installation file for **GWT Developer plugin for IE9**. I searched on Google and found the following URL's but both the URL's don't work...

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/plugins/ie/prebuilt/ 
http://dl.google.com/dl/gwt/plugins/ie/1.0.7263.20091208111100/gwt-dev-plugin.msi

I tried installing it from within IE9, the installation starts but after a while it fails with `The Download Failed` message. See below...

[image]

Can someone please tell me where I can find the standalone installation file. (I am running Windows 7.)

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble installing GWT Developer Plugin for IE through firewall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600226/trouble-installing-gwt-developer-plugin-for-ie-through-firewall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first URL you tried has moved to https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt-plugins/+/master/ie/prebuilt/